# EXTJS Ext.window.Window Handle Width

Tags: extjs

I'm using EXTJS 6.2.0.  When creating a popup using Ext.window.Window the handles to resize the window are about 10px wide. Is there some way to control this?

Answer (score 1):

Classic has a theme css variable $resizer-handle-size
Ext.resizer.Resizer has Theme variables to manipulate the handles, size color etc
[Ext.resizer.Resizer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.resizer.Resizer.html)

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2845) (not mine) that modifies the values via css. Look at app.js and app.css